# * before file name on linux in MidnightCommander

Tags: linux, file, input, txt2tags

I have some files like:

*xxxx.log

*yyy.txt

and I have to convert them to pdf with simple txt2pdf script. Problem is that that * is preventing me from doing that because "cannot open input file xxx.log" (it is not shown with * there)

I was using that on same files some time ago and they were without *, but I can't remember command to remove that from all the files in destination. Is it possible to do so using system command or is it necessary to use a script and if so, can you provide code for doing so.

Comment: normal linux command shell: ./txt2pdf.pl xxx.log

program comes from here, I am not allowed to share it: https://www.sanface.com/txt2pdf.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `\` to escape the special character.

Comment: Though do you know any command to "convert" all the files to remove *?

Comment: You can try this: `for f in $(ls | grep '^\*'); do mv "$f" "${f#\*}"; done`

Comment: @j0k3R: `for f in \** ; do mv "$f" "${f#\*}" ; done`